# What to do or watch out for when school loans are transfered?

Tags: student-loan

I received an email today informing me that one of my student loans has been transfered (Email is below).

Besides following the instructions in the email and some due diligence to make sure this is legit, are there any common gotchas during a loan transfer that I should be aware of?

> Dear Borrower,
>
> This e-mail is to inform you that your Direct Loan, with the Direct
>   Loan Servicing Center, has been transferred to MOHELA.  As the number
>   of Direct Loans continues to grow, Federal Student Aid has expanded
>   their federal loan servicers to provide additional servicing capacity
>   for the Title IV loans owned by the U.S. Department of Education. 
>   This will ensure an efficient and effective multi-servicer,
>   borrower-centric approach to servicing.   You will shortly be
>   receiving correspondence from your new servicer related to the
>   transfer of your Direct Loan.  This will confirm that the new servicer
>   has completed the transfer of your loan at which time you may contact
>   MOHELA by calling 1-888-866-4352 from 8:00 am to 8:00 pm CT Monday
>   through Thursday and 8:00 am to 5:00 pm CT Friday.  You can also visit
>   their website at www.mohela.com
>
> Effective immediately, please submit any required payments to MOHELA. 
>   Make your check or money order payable to MOHELA and mail to:
>
> U.S. Department of Education
>
> PO Box 105347
>
> Atlanta, GA 30348-5347
>
> The Direct Loan Servicing Center will forward any unprocessed
>   applications, such as deferments and forbearances, to MOHELA for
>   processing along with any payments you may have submitted.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Direct Loan Servicing Center

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is: email?

Are you sure it is legitimate? Verify everything.

Assuming it is legitimate:

- Make sure you understand when you should switch to the new service company. You don't want to have a payment get lost in the switch.
- Make sure all the amounts transfer correctly: balance, payment amount, interest rate, number of payments.
- Get a final statement from the old company, and an initial statement from the new company.